# Filter ListEntry on model attribute without column in DB

Tags: php, laravel-backpack

I would like to filter a backpackforlaravel list on a custom calculated Boolean attribute. There is no column for this attribute in the database.

I have created the attribute in the model as an eloquent accessor.

```
public function getCalculatedBooleanAttribute($value)
{
    $bool = // get result of calculation as true/false
    return $bool;
}
```

I can then show the values as a column using the following in my controller.

```
$this->crud->addColumn('calculated_boolean');
```

This works perfectly so far and I can see the expected results in the list view. I now need to filter the view on this...

I have tried a standard crud filter using addClause but this gives an exception about missing database field. e.g

```
$this->crud->addClause('where', 'calculated_boolean', '1');
```

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'calculated_boolean' in 'where clause'`

I cannot find anything in the docs that shows how to filter on this attribute. Can anyone suggest a way to filter on fields without columns in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. Your accessor is just a PHP function that manipulates the MySQL response in some way. Whatever you do inside a Laravel accessor happens AFTER your database response. So you can't add an accessor to an Eloquent query.

It might be possible for you to use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods) to add that column to your query, in the addFilter closure (the third parameter):

```php
$this->crud->addFilter([ // simple filter
  'type' => 'simple',
  'name' => 'active',
  'label'=> 'Active'
], 
false, 
function() { // if the filter is active
    $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->whereRaw('price * ? as calculated_boolean', [1.0825]);
    $this->crud->addClause('where', 'calculated_boolean', '1'); 
} );
```

Notice you can manipulate `$this->crud->query` t

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. I will change my original plan so that calculated_boolean is stored in the database for filtering.